# Spring Boot use SystemTray Icons

Tags: java, spring, system-tray, headless

I am setting up a Spring Boot Application and would like to have the host have access to a System Tray Icon with access to some bean Information.

I currently Tried to Create a Bean for my SystemTrayIcon with the @Autowired details. However When I try to add the SystemTrayIcon I get the following Exception:

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hermes.subsrciber.systemTray.HermesTrayIcon.<init>(HermesTrayIcon.java:36)
    at hermes.subscriber.boot.AppStarter.trayIcon(AppStarter.java:83)
    at hermes.subscriber.boot.AppStarter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4f80849.CGLIB$trayIcon$3(<generated>)
    at hermes.subscriber.boot.AppStarter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4f80849$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d62ab0bd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at hermes.subscriber.boot.AppStarter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4f80849.trayIcon(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 17 more
```

Is there any way that a SpringBoot Application can have access to System Tray Icons?

I believe I CAN simply define it in the Main method (alongisde the SpringApplication.run) however I would not be able to autowire my properties.

Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Solution is, rather than using `SpringApplication.run(MyConfig.class,args)`, use the following setup:

```
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyConfig.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
```

To actually add the System Icon I then added a bean of the followign type:

```
public class MyTrayIcon extends TrayIcon {

    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/path/icon_16x16.png";
    private static final String TOOLTIP = "Text";

    private PopupMenu popup;
    private SystemTray tray;

    public MyTrayIcon(){
        super(createImage(IMAGE_PATH,TOOLTIP),TOOLTIP);
        popup = new PopupMenu();
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() throws AWTException{
        // popup.add(itemAbout);
        // here add the items to your popup menu. These extend MenuItem
        // popup.addSeparator();
        setPopupMenu(popup);
        tray.add(this);
    }

    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description){
        URL imageURL = MyTrayIcon.class.getResource(path);
        if(imageURL == null){
            System.err.println("Failed Creating Image. Resource not found: "+path);
            return null;
        }else {
            return new ImageIcon(imageURL,description).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the bit of code which actually adds the System Tray icon ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html
  That should be fine

Comment: I actually tried exactly that, but strangely SystemTray.isSupported() returns false. Any idea ? (I set builder.headless(false); in case it matters)

Comment: @yglodt did you find a way around this ? I too am getting a java.awt.HeadlessException brought on by SystemTray.isSupported() returning false and I have no idea why...

Comment: Where is MyConfig class?

Comment: 7 year old question so don't remember exactly. but i believe that is just your generic spring configuration class, whatever you have in it basically

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants the full code...

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class MyTrayIcon extends TrayIcon {

    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/PATH.png";
    private static final String TOOLTIP = "Running";
    private PopupMenu popup;
    final SystemTray tray;

    public MyTrayIcon(){
        super(createImage(IMAGE_PATH,TOOLTIP),TOOLTIP);
        popup = new PopupMenu();
        tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        try {
            setup();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() throws AWTException{
        // Create a pop-up menu components
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        popup.add(exitItem);
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final int exitCode = 0;
                ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator = new ExitCodeGenerator() {

                    @Override
                    public int getExitCode() {
                      return exitCode;
                    }

                  };

                  tray.remove(MyTrayIcon.this);
                  SpringApplication.exit(Application.context, exitCodeGenerator);
            }
        });
        // popup.addSeparator();
        setPopupMenu(popup);
        tray.add(this);



    }

    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description){

        URL imageURL = MyTrayIcon.class.getResource(path);
        if(imageURL == null){
            System.err.println("Failed Creating Image. Resource not found: "+path);
            return null;
        }else {
            return new ImageIcon(imageURL,description).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        context = builder.run(args);

        MyTrayIcon m = new MyTrayIcon();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A code logic in use

```
/**
 * @author lotuso
 * @version 1.0 2021/2/21 14:55
 **/
@Slf4j
public class TrayIcon extends Application {
    private final AtomicInteger runCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final RegistryTrayConfiguration configuration = new RegistryTrayConfiguration();
    
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //构建系统托盘图标
        if(configuration.isEnabled()) {
            var stream = TrayIcon.class.getClassLoader().getResource(configuration.getIcon());
            assert stream != null;
            var image = ImageIO.read(stream);
            var trayIcon = new java.awt.TrayIcon(image, configuration.getTip());
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            //添加托盘事件
            {
                trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    //鼠标点击事件
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) {
                        //双击左键
                        if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                            log.info("托盘双击事件");
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                //TODO 如果需要显示一个窗口,哪么在这里进行,暂不实现
                            });
                        }
                        else if(event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                            log.info("托盘右击事件");
                            //TODO 可以做些其它的事
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            
            //获取系统托盘
            var trayPanel = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            trayPanel.add(trayIcon);
        }
    }
    
    public synchronized void run(String... args) {
        if(runCount.get() <= 0){
            runCount.set(runCount.get()+1);
            launch(args);
        }
    }
    
    public static class RegistryTrayConfiguration {
        
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return !Objects.isNull(getIcon());
        }
        
        public String getIcon() {
            var icon = getYML("spring.application.tray.icon");
            return String.valueOf(icon);
        }
        
        public String getTip() {
            var tip = getYML("spring.application.tray.tip");
            return String.valueOf(tip);
        }
        
        public static Object getYML(Object key) {
            return getYML(key, "application.yml");
        }
        
        public static Object getYML(Object key, String yml) {
            var resource = new ClassPathResource(yml);
            Properties properties;
            try {
                var factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
                factory.setResources(resource);
                properties = factory.getObject();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                log.warn(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
            assert properties != null;
            return properties.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Define the following code in the class with the @Configuration tag:

```
@Bean
public Application trayIcon() {
    var trayIcon = new TrayIcon();
    //TODO 此处将托盘与SpringBoot线程分开
    new Thread(trayIcon::run).start();
    return trayIcon;
}
```

Add the resource file with the following structure.
Add the images directory to the project's resources directory and place the icon. PNG file there

```
|_ src
  |_ main
    |_ java
    |_ resources
      |_ images
        |_ icon.png
      |_ application.yml
```

Application.yml requires the following Settings

```
spring:
  application:
    tray:
      tip: Used to indicate the prompt when the mouse is moved over the icon
      icon: Directory path relative to resources, such as images/icon.png
```

In this way, TrayIcon is handed over to Spring's container to manage. If it is helpful to you, please let me know if you have any better suggestions