# Why Is .headless Defaulted To True?

Tags: java, spring, awt

#### Question Setup

There are a few moving parts to this question, so I will try to do my best to replicate the issue in its simplest form.

I am attempting to add a `TrayIcon` to a `SystemTray`. This is typically a very simple objective on operating systems ("platforms") that [support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html#isSupported()) the call (this will play an integral part in a few moments).

I am programming for and on a Windows machine, presently (this is not a question about interoperability).

Here's the logic behind the code I've got that works:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            // DO SOMETHING TO ADD AN ICON
        }
    }
}
```

With all of its inclusions, this works. However, what I am really after, is the ability to inject the `SystemTray` instance with it's icon already "ready to go".

That code looks something a little more like this:

```
public class SomeClass extends NecessarySpringExtension {
    private @Setter(onMethod=@_@Resource(name="SystemTrayControl"))) SystemTrayControl systemTrayControl;
    // The above uses Lombok, as well.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DO SOME RELATED STUFF like setting the configurations for
        // for the application
    }
}
```

The resource returns an instance (`@Bean`) of the `SystemTrayControl` class which, itself, makes a call to `SystemTray`; however, now, `SystemTray` is no longer supported (see some explanation in the **The Question** section, below).

#### Some Change Detail

Here's a snippet of some of that code (obviously, I've got my head submerged in the issue. Let me know if the context needs expanding. My belief is the following should be enough code to give you a sense of the structure):

**SystemTrayControl** Class:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void showIcon() {

        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            val tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray(); ....
```

**Resource** Class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansForNeeds {

    @Bean
    public SystemTrayControl systemTrayControl() {
        return new SystemTrayControl():
    } ....
```

For the sake of more context: if I remove the condition seen in the `SystemTrayControl` class , I get a [HeadlessException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) (which I've done a bit of reading on).

#### The Question

The issue stems from that fact that when utilizing a `SpringApplicationBuilder` in your program, the `.headless` property defaults to true. The javadoc states:

> Sets if the application is headless and should not instantiate AWT.
>   Defaults to true to prevent java icons appearing

If I manually set the property to `false`, then the application runs well; however, I am always a bit "shaky" overwriting default behavior, particular if the language of "prevents" x, y, or z makes into the mix.

So, the question is:

Why is the property defaulted to true? What are the side effects of allowing the behavior prohibited by `.headless`? What's it got against AWT?

Comment: I've noticed a similar question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564077/spring-boot-use-systemtray-icons?rq=1 However, the accepted answer doesn't elaborate on the reason why what is suggested works and possible side effects.

Comment: Once upon a time, pulling in the AWT classes (and native stuff) on a true headless box like Unix without X would cause runtime exceptions. You had to be careful in your startup code to not accidentally use a handy utility class if it touched AWT, because then all of it would be pulled in, and fall over as it ran into missing native UI.

Comment: @jdv that makes sense, thank you. Any reason you are not posting as an answer?

Comment: my memory is hazy and my notes long-gone. It was a tricky bug I worked on for an AIX product. But I can try to make it more answer-friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once upon a time, pulling in the AWT classes (and native stuff) on a true headless box like Unix without X would cause runtime exceptions and other nasty OS level failures. And the errors would only happen once the classes were loaded, so it could be slightly non-deterministic.

This was with Java 6 or so, I recall.Things may have changed since then. And I suppose it is important that it was a problem only for the AIX Java, which is a clean-room Java that is not based on the Sun reference implementation. It wasn't *strictly* a bug, though, because the reference implementations just escaped the same problem by mistake when I looked at the code for each.

In my case, we had to be careful in some startup code to not accidentally use a handy utility class if it touched AWT, because then all of it would be pulled in, and fall over as it ran into missing native UI. This would never happen on Windows, where a lot of development took place. But once deployed on a true headless AIX box the app would fail hard with a runtime exception that bubbled right up to the user.

This is because we had "client" code (that was, ostensibly, headless and did not rely on the any UI code) and "UI" code (that knew how to interact with a command line or a full Swing GUI.) The client code was changed such that it pulled in some handy utility class (I forget which one) but this caused the VM to pull in some other classes, which pulled in AWT, which hit some native code expecting there to be a native UI of some sort.

Since the AIX box had no X, these native components were not there, and the whole thing fell apart with a translated native/runtime exception.

So, not only did we have to run the VM headless, we had to make sure our code did not accidentally reference any AWT code, either directly or indirectly.

I'd want to do more research to see how this scenario interacts with the property discussed here, but the key takeaway for me is that cross-platform *means* cross-platform! And "headless" can mean something very specific on different platforms.